# Admob in phonegap android suddenly stop working

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I've intergrated admob into my android phonegap app using the smartphone web method. In test mode, test ad will be shown everytime i open the app. Testing with live ad also a success, although sometimes it does not show. A few weeks ago, I noticed that my app no longer show any ad. Change to test mode also will not shown the test ad.

I check the logcat, and found these 2 errors.

> 12-02 08:12:15.394: D/PhoneGapLog(1824):
>   http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js: Line 1 : TypeError:
>   Result of expression 'R[Z]' [undefined] is not an object.
>
> 12-02 08:12:15.394: E/Web Console(1824): TypeError: Result of
>   expression 'R[Z]' [undefined] is not an object. at
>   http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js:1

Are the 2 lines above causing the admob not working? Anyone encounter this problem before? Thank you.

EDIT:
I use this javascript code to load the ads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
 pubid: my_pub_ID,
 bgcolor: '7F90AA',
 text: 'FFFFFF',
 test: true
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm just getting started with admob for my HTML5 based web app (using phonegap) and I am not receiving test ads either.  Since this is my first go at admob, I don't know if it's something wrong with my code or something else.  Are you still having this problem or is it resolved for you?

Comment: The problem still exist. I've followed the startup guide properly, even trying with new empty project. But still doesn't work...

Comment: @eastwest, did your test ads fly up in th result? Mine not also: not yesterday and not today.

Comment: @gaRex, I'm not sure what happen, but on wednesday, one ad did appear(live ad) but it just appear one time only. On the admob site, it did show the request made by my app, and since then no other ad appear. The test ad never appear at all.

Comment: ok, now the ad is working... Created a new admob account. Then, I use the manual_mode to fetch the ad. But the test ad never work..

Answer (score 0):

Test ads weren't working yesterday, but they are back up again.  Also, in general there isn't a 100% fill rate on live ads.  Have you tried getting back test ads again?

Comment: Just try the test ads, but no ads was displayed... Still get the same error message as in my post. I've tried creating a new clean project which contains only the admob script but still failed.

Comment: Anyone can help me troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not very familiar with the smartphone web version of AdMob ads.  I thought another issue with all test ads not working may have been related, but I guess it's not.